# mysql to mysqli change, trouble with mysqli_real_escape_string

Tags: php, mysqli

try to upgrade my application to mysqli. now i have the following problem:

Connection (in an external inc. file, works fine)

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect ($DB_HOST, $DB_BN, $DB_PW) or die ('Datenbank konnte nicht erreicht werden: ' . mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db ($DB_DB);
```

Select:

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_one WHERE bLogin = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($benu)."'");
```

The mysql_real_escape_string doesn't work well, the var $benu is ''..

thanks for help

Comment: Read the manuals and learn http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - Your code is failing on all counts.

Comment: how do you know that **The mysql_real_escape_string doesn't work well, the var $benu is '**

Comment: You'll need to supply the connection object to the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function call as well as the value you want to escape

Comment: *"Connection (in an external inc. file, works fine)"* - I doubt that very much. The file exists, sure... but that connection to the db will never happen.

Comment: So if the var `$benu` is blank, that is before you apply `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Check your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with `mysqli_select_db()`. It expects parameter 1 to be $link of the connection.

```
mysqli_select_db ($dbh, $DB_DB);
```

Or you could just select the db when calling the `mysqli_connect()` function :

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect ($DB_HOST, $DB_BN, $DB_PW, $DB_DB) or die ('Datenbank konnte nicht erreicht werden: ' . mysqli_error());
```

**And function `mysqli_real_escape_string()` also expects parameter 1 to be `$link`**

```
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $benu);
```